# jQuery xPath selector, &&

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I'm using jQuery to run through all the inputs within a section that I have set from hidden to show, and add required calsses, so as to catch the validation.

```
$("#" + dependant).find("input[type!='radio']").addClass('required');
```

Works fine, but I also want to exclude the submits. In normal xPath I would;

input[type!='radio' and type!='submit']

I acheived a work around using .each() and an additional IF;

```
$("#" + dependant).find("input[type!='radio']").each(function()
{
    if ($(this).attr(type) != 'submit')
    {
        $(this).addClass('required')
    }
});
```

But it strikes me there must be an easier, cleaner way of combining contraints....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Traversing and Selectors in the jQuery docs.

```
$("#" + dependant).find(":input").not(':radio').not(':submit').addClass('required');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#" + dependant).find("input[type!='radio'][type!='submit']").addClass('required');
```

See [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/):

> **Description**: Matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters.